# python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, c++, json, utf-8

I am trying to create a C++ file encoded in UTF-8. Actually when i try to create a file like that:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream myfile("test.json");
    myfile << "{\"test\":\"é\"}";
    myfile.close();
}
```

then python can't decode it as UTF-8 and i have to decode it using ISO-8859-1:

```
import json
import codecs

with codecs.open('test.json', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data)
```

And when i set encoding to utf8 i get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

How can i make this file UTF-8 encoded using C++ ? I really need this file to be UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1.

I also tried creating the json using Vim (not using c++), and it worked.

Comment: Did you try `codecs.open('test.json', encoding='utf-8')` ?

Comment: yes, that's how i get the error, and if i set nothing, it's by default utf8

Comment: Have you tried to prefix your c++ string literal with u8. `u8"é"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your text editor / IDE.

C++ is just writing bytes to the output file, and those bytes take the form of the text you write in your source code (since the data is a string literal). As such, they have the encoding specified by your text editor / IDE. Ensure that the setting is UTF-8.

At present, your editor appears to be configured to write some other encoding. Then, when trying to decode UTF-8 codepoints from the result, the Python script is encountering something different and telling you about it.

That your solution worked when you changed editors to Vim supports this.

Alternatively, you can make it a UTF-8 string literal (`u8"é"`). This should trigger re-encoding internally if the source file *wasn't* UTF-8, though I'm not sure of the extent to which this works reliably in the modern ecosystem.